# Website shows sometimes character N; (php, php-apc, nginx)

Tags: nginx, apc, php

My website is written in PHP and with a chance of 0.1% website shows instead of my content these two symbols **N;**

Could this be the problem of php code or webserver itself or...?
Maybe nginx gzip compression?

```
nginx 1.2.1
php5-fpm 5.4.4
php-apc 3.1.13 (maybe move to xcache?)
```

Not sure, if it belongs to stackoverflow or to serverfault due to unknown cause of the problem.

Comment: you should check through your code to see if there's some obscure condition that can cause that output, it looks like a coding error.

Comment: Website is huge and I never had similar problem, how could i find the problem? Some debug options?

Comment: I would start with a grep of `N;` exactly, it can't be in that many places.